# SAX finding nodes at max depth

Tags: java, xml, sax

How can i display node names with the maximum depth in the tree with SAX.
The algorithm would be fine for me to understand the concept..

For example what should i do with startelement, endelement, startdocument, enddocument methods and what variables do i need to perform the task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an algorithmic problem. The thing to note in order to solve the problem is that each time you have a startelement event you have gone one level down and when you have an endelement event you have gone one level up. The idea is to have a variable (level) and for each startelement increase it (level++) and for each endelement decrease it (level--). This means that when find the endelement for a node the value of level variable would be the depth of the node. Then the only thing you have to do is just keep track of the max. A pseudocode version will be like this:

```
 startdocument -> level=0;max=0;
 startelement  -> level++
 endelement    -> if (level>max) max=level; level--; 
 endocument    -> System.out.println(max)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this really helped. But this will print the max depth as a number. To display the deepest nodes.I guess i can have a 2d array or hashlist and store node name and level in endelement, then select the maximum level with the names of the nodes in the enddocument.. do you think would it be right?

Comment: Seems like a good plan. If I were you I would not keep track of the nodes and levels, I would first find the maximum depth and then go through the xml again using sax parser and the level variable and where level == max I would print the node.

Comment: Keep a set of nodenames found at the max depth. When you find a new max (level>max) clear the set and then add the name of this node. When you find a new node at the same depth as the max (level=max), add the name of this node to the set.